# How to change the linear gradient color of navbar button in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Navigation bar with Linear Gradient Color in Button](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/10171134_10204191852384830_2201605228222022874_n.jpg)

When I Hover/Focus at **Client Application Button**, It give black linear gradient color...

How can I change that black linear gradient color?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @EvanPurkhiser Bootstrap 3, By the way I used a template from bootswatch.com. The one i used is this [Slate Template](http://bootswatch.com/slate/)

Comment: Is the template itself broken? or did you change the background color of the navigation menu and it was originally black? Can you mention which template. Edit: Just saw you mentioned this :p

Comment: @EvanPurkhiser The navigation menu was originally black. My problem is I need to change the color when you hover/focus to the menu.

The Template I used [Slate Template](http://bootswatch.com/slate/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your stylesheet add something similar to this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
   background-image: linear-gradient(#020202, #101112 40%, #191B1D);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
   background-color: #272B2E;
}
```

Make sure you change the hex values to the colors you want.

You can read more about how the `liniar-gradient` works [on the MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Source: [I looked at the slate bootswatch theme here](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/gh-pages/slate/bootswatch.less).